# Python scraping logic in Google search

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import requests,re


def parse_google(item,x=1):
    # item["Name"]="Cookware Set 12-Piece Black"
    # item["Name"]= "Zipit Jumbo Pencil Case - Orange"

    sellers=["target","ebay","homedepot"]   
    google_search_url= 'https://google.com/search?hl={}&q={}'.format('en', item["Name"].replace(" ","%20"))

    response = requests.get(google_search_url,headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    rows=Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="g"]')
    for row in rows:
        try:
            needed_text = row.xpath('div/div[@class="rc"]/div[@class="s"]/div/div[@class="slp f"]/text()').extract_first().encode("utf-8").decode("ascii","ignore")
            domain = row.xpath('div/div[@class="rc"]/div[@class="r"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            for seller in sellers:
                if seller in domain:
                    Merchant = seller.title()
                    break
                else:
                    Merchant=None
            if "$" in needed_text and Merchant is not None:             
                text=needed_text
                price = re.search('.*\$(.*)-',text).groups().replace(" ","").replace(",","").replace(";","")
                if "in stock" in text.lower():
                    stock = True
                elif "out of stock" in text.lower():
                    stock = False
                else:
                    stock = "Not determined"
                item["Merchant %d"%x] = Merchant
                item["Merchant %d Price"%x] = price
                item["Merchant %d link"%x] = domain
                item["Stock %d"%x] = stock
                x+=1
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    next_page = Selector(response).xpath('//a[@id="pnnext"]/@href').extract_first()
```

Hi, i wrote the following function i need help some logic,what I am trying to do is to find only the first **two merchants** from Google search that has  product and a price for it and i want to search only the first two pages and fill `item` dictionary, if Merchant isn't found `item` fields "N/a".

i.e find the first two merchants in the **only** first two pages, if not found fill the fields "N/a", if both are found on page 1 no need for page 2.

Also this is my first question,please be nice.

Comment: A bit of an out of topic question, but why scrapping Google instead of using their REST API?

Comment: @Adonis it is just for 20 products no need to API, also My problem is that I can't find the logic to do what I want, the code works

Comment: Where does your code not behave as expected?

Comment: @Gallaecio ok if you read the question, My code works it gives the expected outputs, what I want to do is make it search for 2 Merchants from the first two pages, if both are found in the first page no need to visit the second, if any of them isn't found make Merchant fields "N/a"

Comment: I meant: What’s the difference between what your code does, and what you want it to do? Also, you might want to simplify your code further (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gallaecio first of it always goes to next page and only 1 merchant in yielded, Also this is the simplified version